Why doesn't Text in an HStack animate properly when disabled?
The image inside the HStack animates but the text just snaps between its original and new position. I've boiled it down to the .disabled modifier being the culprit for the strange behavior. The spacing in the VStack is exaggerated for the problem to be clearly visible.
Demo video of the isssue
The following contains the minimum reproducible code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showTitle: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            if(showTitle) {
                Text("Title")
            }
                Button {} label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "cloud")
                        Text("Cloud")
                    }
                    .disabled(showTitle)
                    .animation(.default, value: showTitle)
                }
            Button("Toggle"){
                showTitle.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried .drawingGroup, which works, but it ruins some other styling elements like .clipShape, which I would like to use.
Running the code without the .disabled modifier is how I expect the animation to look like. Edit: Must support iOS 16+
Edit 2: Running on 16.4 fixes the timing issue but also contains an issue where the characters rearrange during the animation. Example contains a Label and HStack with Image and Text.

I can't confirm. I put your code in a fresh iOS Project on Xcode 14.2, macOS 12.7.6 and it animates fine, both Text and Image together, in Simulator. Please share your system details.

Move disabled and animation out of the button's label, and apply it to the Button directly. You are trying to disable the Button, not the HStack .
Button {} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "cloud")
        Text("Cloud")
    }
}
.disabled(showTitle)
.animation(.default, value: showTitle)


If you really want to put these on the label for some reason (this doesn't really make sense to me), it is also possible to use geometryGroup instead of drawingGroup. Since this only isolates the geometry of the view, and not the whole drawing, clip shapes and such will not be affected.
Button {} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "cloud")
        Text("Cloud")
    }
    .disabled(showTitle)
    .geometryGroup()
    .animation(.default, value: showTitle)
}


thanks for your answer, but placing the modifiers outside didn't make any change to the animation. .geometryGroup did solve it however I forgot to mention that iOS 16 is a requirement. I will update the original question.

@dingomingo I cannot reproduce that. In fact, I cannot reproduce the broken animation using your original code on iOS 16.4 at all. It is broken in iOS 17.4 and moving the modifiers outside produces the expected animation on both iOS 17.4 and 16.4. What versions are you running?

I'm running 17.5 on both sim and phyiscal device and both produce the first gif i uploaded, however the issue partly remains on 16.4. I've added a slowed down gif of the problem, pay attention to the kerning of the chars.

Your HStack does not contain any user-interactive view that disabled could have an effect on. You probably want to disable Button, so put the modifier after its label closure.
Button {} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "cloud")
        Text("Cloud")
    }
}
.disabled(showTitle)
.animation(.default, value: showTitle)

For a simple label with text and image there's also Label(_:systemImage:) that groups both, like:
Button {} label: {
    HStack {
        Label("Cloud", systemImage: "cloud")
    }
}
.disabled(showTitle)
.animation(.default, value: showTitle)

Using Label also removes the jittery shift in the animated text that I see when using the single views.
